# Joining a domain breaks Ctrl+Alt+Del functionality

Tags: vnc, domain, ultravnc, ctrl-alt-delete

I have several computers that have been in place running UltraVNC for a little over a year. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key sequence that can be sent from UltraVNC has been working fine up to this point. Recently, these computers have been joined to a domain, and upon joining, I've found that the remote machine will no longer accept the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> sequence from either UltraVNC or GoToMyPC. I've followed through with several of the solutions online, including the one detailed in the GoToMyPC administrator's guide (which covers setting the Secure Attention Sequence and setting UAC to the notch just above being off), but haven't had any luck.

Does anyone know of any other settings that I should be checking other than UAC and the SAS GPO?

Comment: Does it still accept local ctrl-alt-del?

Comment: @ZaB Yes, the user is still able to send Ctrl+Alt+Del from the local keyboard.